# How can i simulate a "click" on a website, without clicking? To read the response message before to real click

Tags: javascript, web, request, simulation

is there any way to send a "***fake***" *request* to a server, via a website, to analyze the response and then make the real request?
I'll give you an example: if on a website i click on a button, the site shows me a message. I need to simulate the button click because im trying to know in advance what the response message would be to the click, but **without actually clicking** on the button. Thank you. Have a good day!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You could try and read the JS scripts on the page and deduct what would clicking that element do, but usually the scripts are mangled, so it would be hard to read. You could try searching them via class or id of the element of interest.
2. You could try playing with blocking network traffic, so you could still do the action, without sending the request. It might prove fruitless as the result might be dependent on getting a valid response from the server, but still it could be worth a shot.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i don't know how the communication between client and server works but i was thinking, if i send a request and the server replies, does my client need to give confirmation of receipt? in this case it would be possible not to send my confirmation of receipt, but in the meantime read the message from the server?